# Google Sheets Script XML Return ID Name

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the ID name from an Goodreads xml file.
I am trying to return all the shelf name IDs and would like to return it in a single line with ", " replacing new lines.

This is what I have but faling

```
function GetSHELVES(ID) {
 book = encodeURIComponent(ID);
  var url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/' + ID + '.xml?key=REDACTED';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  var xml = XmlService.parse(response);

  var root = xml.getRootElement();

  var BookSHELVES = root
    .getChild('book')
    .getChild('popular_shelves')
    .getAttribute('shelf name')
    .getValue();

  Logger.log(BookSHELVES);
return BookSHELVES;
}
```

and here is a sample xml sheet

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

    <GoodreadsResponse>
    <Request>
    <authentication>true</authentication>
    <key>...</key>
    <method>
    <![CDATA[ book_show ]]>
    </method>
    </Request>
    <book>
    <popular_shelves>
    <shelf name="to-read" count="437"/>
    <shelf name="fantasy" count="31"/>
    <shelf name="audible" count="19"/>
    <shelf name="urban-fantasy" count="16"/>
    <shelf name="audiobook" count="15"/>
    <shelf name="audiobooks" count="12"/>
    <shelf name="audio-books" count="10"/>
    <shelf name="audio" count="9"/>
    <shelf name="alternate-history" count="7"/>
    </popular_shelves>
    </book>
    </GoodreadsResponse>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to parse and retrieve the result using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `root.getChild("book").getChild("popular_shelves")` is correct. But `popular_shelves` has several `shelf`. So it retrieves all `shelf` using `getChildren()`.
- At your XML value, `name="###"` can be retrieved by `getAttribute("name").getValue()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows and try again.

From:

```
var BookSHELVES = root
  .getChild('book')
  .getChild('popular_shelves')
  .getAttribute('shelf name')
  .getValue();
```

To:

```
var popularShelves = root.getChild("book").getChild("popular_shelves").getChildren();
var BookSHELVES = popularShelves.map(function(shelf) {return shelf.getAttribute("name").getValue()}).join(",");
```

Result:

```
to-read,fantasy,audible,urban-fantasy,audiobook,audiobooks,audio-books,audio,alternate-history
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that `response` in your script is the XML value in your question.

#### References:

- [getChildren()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getChildren())
- [getAttribute()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getAttribute(String))

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: @itschrisonline Thank you for your response.